# How does one get Oracle's Python MySQL driver to work with django 1.11?

Tags: django, django-models

I installed on ubuntu 16.04 django 1.11 using pip3 and then installed the oracle mysql-connector-python.  Why is this error occurring? How can I resolve it?  According to the tutorial migrations will run even if there are no models defined.

Installed by using pip3

```
pip3 install --egg http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-Python/mysql-connector-python-2.1.6.zip
```

My database configuration

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'user_data',
        'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
        'USER': 'mysql_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'priv4te',
        'OPTIONS': {
          'autocommit': True,
        },
    }
}
```

The command that I ran
    python3 /home/django/workspace/mysite/manage.py migrate

The Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/django/workspace/mysite/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/django/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/django/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/django/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/django/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home/django/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/django/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/home/django/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 52, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/home/django/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 124, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/home/django/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 330, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/home/django/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 214, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/home/django/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/home/django/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 212, in __getitem__
    conn = backend.DatabaseWrapper(db, alias)
  File "/home/django/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mysql/connector/django/base.py", line 336, in __init__
    super(DatabaseWrapper, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/django/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 96, in __init__
    self.client = self.client_class(self)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
Finished "/home/django/workspace/mysite/manage.py migrate" execution.
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this question as I'm having the same issue. There is apparently a known bug.

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=86105